# illegal string offset 'name' when working with password fields laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

hi i have this custom validation i declared in my start->global.php what it does is compare the password inside the database and the entered 'current password' here is the code

```
Validator::extend('chkcpass', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    $getAcc = DB::table('nsa_systemusers')
           ->where('sid' , '=' , $parameters)
           ->get();

    foreach ($getAcc as $key => $gcp){
        $ucp = $gcp->password;
    }

    $sptkey  = md5('3982f3a0c86f272633fc7105040a83c8');
    $decPass = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sptkey, base64_decode($ucp), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

    if($value != $decPass){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
});
```

in my controller im calling it like this

```
$uid = Session::get('sid');
$rules = array(
    'ecp'   => 'required|min:8|max:255|chkcpass:'.$uid,
    'np'    => 'required',
    'rnp'   => 'required',
);
```

and in my view here is the form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'usrchangepassword')) }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
        {{ Form::label('pass', 'Enter Current Password') }} 
        {{ Form::password('ecp' , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
        {{ Form::label('pass', 'Enter New Password') }} 
        {{ Form::password('np' , array('class' => 'form-control ')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
        {{ Form::label('pass', 'Re-type New Password') }} 
        {{ Form::password('rnp' , array('class' => 'form-control ')) }}
    </div> 
</div>
@if ($errors->any())
<div class='err'>
    <ul>
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<strong><li class="ermsg">:message</li></strong>')) }} 
    </ul> 
</div>
@endif
<br>
{{ Form::submit('save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary savebtn')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

but im getting an error saying i have an error in my view blade about

```
Illegal string offset 'name'
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong? thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $getAcc = DB::table('nsa_systemusers')
     ->where('sid' , '=' , $parameters)
     ->get();
```

It is failing because `$parameters` is an array.

If you want to use the array, then use this method:

```
->whereIn('sid', $parameters);
```